# Chat application online status

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a chat app. Everything is working except one thing. So I want the users to see if the person they chat whit is online. I made that work but now every time the person is going in on an other chat the online status blink. I have found where the problem is but I dont know how to fix it.

So when a person1 is in the chat it can see a green box where it says online if person2 is online. But if person2 is going in to a chat the green box will blink for person1.

The problem is in onResume and onPause. So when person2 is going from mainActivity to chatActivity it will do onPause() on mainActivity and set online to 0 and the do onResume() on chatActivity where it sets it to 1.

I know that the order is ActivityA.onPause, ActivityB.onCreate, ActivityB.onStart, ActivityB.onResume, ActivityA.onStop. So I dont want it to do onPause() when it going from one Activity to another Activity but still do it when you tab down or close the app. is that possible?

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DocumentReference documentReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new          
            PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        documentReference = database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
                .document(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        documentReference.update(Constants.KEY_AVAILABLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        documentReference.update(Constants.KEY_AVAILABLE, 1);
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        init();
        loadUserDetails();
        getToken();
        setListeners();
        listenConversations();
    }

}
```

```
public class ChatActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setListeners();
        loadReceiverDetails();
        init();
        listenMessages();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        listenAvailabilityOfReceiver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did fix it in a ugly way. I made variable that knows if the user is still in the app or not.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!stillInApp) {
        DocumentReference documentReference;
        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new         
            PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        documentReference = database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
            .document(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
        documentReference.update(Constants.KEY_AVAILABLE, 0);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DocumentReference documentReference;
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new 
        PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
    FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    documentReference = database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
    documentReference.update(Constants.KEY_AVAILABLE, 1);
    stillInApp = false;
    listenAvailabilityOfReceiver();
}
```